# How to get the last date of next month in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find out the **last day of the next month**.
I tried but couldn't find out.

Example: `Date.today.end_of_month.next_month`

Comment: I don't think it can be done like that in plain Ruby but check out Rails Active Support: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date

Comment: try this `(Date.today + 1.month).end_of_month`

Comment: @MitchWheat what do mean by that? 
I tried with existing ruby methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in `Rails` or with `Active Support`:

```
(Date.today + 1.month).end_of_month
```

or with time:

```
1.month.from_now.end_of_month
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Date.today.next_month.end_of_month
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
(Date.today + 1.month).end_of_month
```